# Handling exceptions/failures using Rest Assured and TestNG

Tags: java, testng, try-catch, assert, rest-assured

I'm trying to find a universal way of handling errors in my tests which use TestNG as the framework and Rest Assured as the library to make REST calls.

And in some of Rest Assured @Test annotated methods I enclose within try/catch:

```
    @Test
    public void readyForSend(String uid) {

        try{

        Response response =

        given().header("X-AI-Test-ID","new-shop-user").
               spec(requestSpecUserCreationService).
        when().
               get("/api/v11/new/createUser?uid=" + uid ).
        then().
              assertThat().statusCode(200);
        catch(AssertionError ae){
            logger.info("Unable to create new user");
        }
    }
```

In my TestNG file, I have the following set:

```
<suite name="create new user" verbose="1" configfailurepolicy="continue">
```

I have over 30 REST calls to make for each iteration and am using e.g. `invocationCount = 10` so one single Rest Assured failure that does not have it's own try/catch and the whole lot fail.  Must I enclose each in a try/catch or is there a better way of doing a 'soft assertion' so the tests do not bomb on me if not handled individually?

Comment: Did you try `@Test(alwaysRun=true)` ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to simply make a method, which encapsulates the get and other post calls.  You can do further exception handling in this method as well.
The status code can be returned and a soft assert can be done post that.
eg.

```
 public static Response doGet(String endpoint) {
            Response response = given(defaultRequestSpec).when().get(endpoint).andReturn();
//defaultRequestSpec can hold your headers, if they are common or pass as arguments
            return response;
        }
```

In your @Test method, make a call to this method

```
 @Test(invocationCount=10) {
        SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
        softAssert.assertEquals(this.doGet("/api/v11/new/createUser?uid=...").statusCode(), 200, "Verify createUser response is 200");
    ....
    //further api calls
    softAssert.assertAll();
 }
```